# Discord.py, Unable to fetch embed message

Tags: python, discord.py

I am using `discord.py` library to ineract with Discord and read the DMed message. I am using the following code, despite of fetching authod and display name, it is unable to read embeds. Though the embed is right there. What am I doing wrong?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id in bots_id:
        print(ctx.author.id, ctx.author.display_name)
        print(ctx) # Prints nothing, empty.
        if len(ctx.embeds) > 0:
            print(ctx.embeds[0].to_dict())
            await send_embed(ctx.embeds[0].to_dict())
```

Comment: Works fine when I test this code, at least when using `print` on the embeds. What exactly is not working?

Comment: @Benjin the line `print(ctx)` prints nothing, shows blank line, it does print author id and display_name

Comment: The `on_message` event normally takes the `message` parameter. If it does not print any `message` or `message.content`, depends on what you have tried, try to activate the Intent even though it should not be necessary. Sometimes other `on_message` events are also blocking the code.

Comment: @Dominik I am passing `ctx` parameter here as you can see. I will try `.content` and will update here

Comment: @Volatil3 I saw it, but I was just pointing out that it normally takes `message` as the parameter. I do not know if in theory or praxis, the `ctx` parameter is causing some trouble here.

Comment: If you just want the message itself, then in your case use `print(ctx.content)`. Embeds are a different type of message. @Dominik It's just naming convention. The first argument of `on_message` is a `Message` object, so people normally call it `message`. But you can call it whatever you want, in this case it's called `ctx`.

Comment: Could you please also show the `bots_id` variable definition, as well as the output of your code with all those prints ?